# Highcharts don't connect points between years

Tags: highcharts

Is it possible not to connect points between years? See screenshot of graph below. I've been told it's misleading. My only solution so far is to create year end nulls for each sample year of each station. That's about 750 entries in SQL table. Seems crude. Can anyone come up with a more elegant and programmatic solution.

Data is retrieved via json from Postgresql.

Any suggestions or references would be greatly appreciated,

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Gaps in series can be created through null value points.

Other option is to place data for each year in different series that will be linked together and have same color options and names.

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/kcccL6vw/1/

```
$(function () {
    $('#container').highcharts({
        xAxis: {
            type: 'datetime'
        },
        series: [{
            pointStart: Date.UTC(2013, 11, 30),
            pointInterval: 3,
            pointIntervalUnit: 'month',
            data: [1,2,3,4,5],
            name: 'Series',
            id: 'S1',
            color: '#fa0'
        },{
            pointStart: Date.UTC(2015, 0, 15),
            pointInterval: 3,
            pointIntervalUnit: 'month',
            data: [1,2,3,4,5],
            name: 'Series',
            linkedTo: 'S1',
            color: '#fa0'
        }]
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use scatter plot instead of line chart if you dont want to connect points.

type:'scatter'

Comment: Tried that. They want a line, but didn't want the line connected from one year to the next due to gaps in sample data. Some gaps could be as much as 6 months. Guess I'll have to go with year end nulls with connectNulls: false. Thanks

Comment: You can set a [breaks on axis](http://api.highcharts.com/highstock#xAxis.breaks) or use [gaps](http://api.highcharts.com/highstock#plotOptions.line.gapSize) or push null values for missing points.

Comment: with breaks on axis,is it possible to ignore the year and have the breaks between 12/31 am and 12/31 pm every year? I'll post another question with jsfiddle

Answer (score 0):

It's ugly but it works for now. I got the year range of existing data then appended records with all year end('12/31/20xx')null values to existing data. connectNulls: false prevented any points connecting to them.Then sorted the array by date which was unnecessarily difficult.

I know my JavaScript skills suck, so if anyone sees a way to tighten it up, please respond. I need all the help i can get. Here's my [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/help/q5kzduzk/) I was working from

Thanks to all for help and suggestions,

Michael

```
var cruiseDate = [];

for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    sampleDate = data[i][1];
    thisDate = moment(sampleDate).format('MM/DD/YYYY');
    cruiseDate.push([thisDate]);
}

var minDate = moment(cruiseDate[0], "MM/DD/YYYY").year();
var maxDate = moment(cruiseDate[cruiseDate.length - 1], "MM/DD/YYYY").year();
console.log('first year: ' + minDate + '  last year:  ' + maxDate);

for (var i = minDate; i <= maxDate; i++) {
    temp = null;
    insertDate = moment('12/31/' + i).valueOf();
    console.log('epoch: ' + insertDate + '  ' + moment(insertDate).format("MM/DD/YYYY"));
    data.push(["year-end-null", insertDate, 0, temp, temp, temp, temp, temp, temp, temp, temp, temp, temp, temp, temp, temp])
}

function compare(a, b) { // from stackoverflow
    var aDate = new Date(a[1]);
    var bDate = new Date(b[1]);
    if (aDate < bDate) return -1;
    if (aDate > bDate) return 1;
    return 0;
}

data.sort(compare);
```